# Replacing Google Site Search with AWS Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, web-crawler

So I'm working on a site that has pretty specific global site search functionality that utilizes GSS which, as many of you already know, is going away in April. I need to crawl the site and send XML over to Cloudsearch, but I'm kind of confused as to how to go about this and I haven't found much material on building a global site search using AWS Cloudsearch after scouring the internet for a couple of days. So far, I'm planning on crawling the site with Apache Nutch, but I would really appreciate some input.

Comment: have you read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/what-is-cloudsearch.html ?

Comment: @RicardoC I've been reading through them for the past couple of days, but the docs don't to my knowledge discuss the use of a crawler specifically.

Comment: Amazon CloudSearch is not a web crawler.

Answer (score 4):

Did you come across our blog? [Index the web with AWS CloudSearch](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html) [Index the web with StormCrawler (revisited)](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2016/09/index-web-with-stormcrawler-revisited.html). I described how to use Nutch and StormCrawler to index to AWS Cloudsearch.

If you need the search to be hosted, I'd recommend Elasticsearch and [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud) instead. I found Cloudsearch slow, cumbersome and expensive and also there are more resources for Elasticsearch for StormCrawler and Apache Nutch.

Comment: I have read your first article that mentions Nutch. I really appreciate the Elasticsearch suggestion. I'm in a bit of a scramble at the moment working on a site and trying to find an alternative for Google Site Search. Do you think the Elastic Cloud would be a decent replacement? It sucks but it seems like Google's left a huuuuge void in that particular market. Thanks again!

Comment: @EthanStepanian you are welcome. Elastic Cloud won't help with the crawl itself but combined with StormCrawler it would be a good approach. Alternatively there are hosted solutions based on Apache SOLR and you could  use another crawler like Nutch.